# How to send email of image in django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have tried to send image in email. I have mentioned the code below.Can anyone plz check What mistake i did. I mentioned the code below

```
 msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, to, cc='',headers =sendgrid )
 msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
 #print "path",os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/instance/errorscreenshot/'+Image)
 for attachment in self.request.FILES.getlist("attachment"):
       #Path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/instance/errorscreenshot/'+attachment) ---->>>>> when i tried to give path of image, then also am getting error like "cannot concatenate str and InMemoryUploadedFile object"**
       #print "path",attachment
       fp = open(attachment,'rb')
       msg_img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
       msg.attach(msg_img)

 msg.send(fail_silently=False)
```

am getting the error like below
**coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found**

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error message? Currently it's not clear the exception is actually raised from. Also, why are you trying to re-open the uploaded file? Django uploaded file objects have a `read()` method.

Comment: I would like to send email of that uploaded image. that's y am trying to read

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `open()` with a django-managed file as first parameter. `open()` wants the path to the file as first argument, and you are not passing one, hence the error message.

Instead, Django provides a file abstraction API, which allows you to directly read the image data from the uploaded file object provided to you by Django:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(...)
# [...]
for attachment in self.request.FILES.getlist("attachment"):
    # rewind file object, make sure it's open
    img_file.open('rb')
    try:
        # directly read in data from uploaded file object
        img_data = img_file.read()
        msg_img = MIMEImage(img_data)
        msg.attach(msg_img)
    finally:
        # not strictly mandated by django, but why not
        img_file.close()

msg.send()
```

PS.: Your original code could potentially leak a file descriptor. Always try to combine `with` with `open`.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
import os
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage

# You probably want all the following code in a function or method.
# You also need to set subject, sender and to_mail yourself.
html_content = render_to_string('foo.html', context)
text_content = render_to_string('foo.txt', context)
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content,
                             sender, [to_mail])

msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

msg.mixed_subtype = 'related'

for f in ['img1.png', 'img2.png']:
    fp = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f), 'rb')
    msg_img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    msg_img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(f))
    msg.attach(msg_img)

msg.send()
```

Source:[Sending emails with embedded images in Django](https://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2014/01/15/sending-emails-with-embedded-images-in-django/)

Comment: How does this solve OP's problem that he cannot get the image data from a form upload?